# Value [2015-07-16T09:46:09.755Z] for parameter Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am using amazon product advertising API to search for a product.
But its showing me following error

```
 <ItemLookupErrorResponse><Error><Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code><Message>Value [2015-07-16T15:32:47Z] for parameter Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format.</Message></Error><RequestId>6ad7b331-1eb3-4565-98c0-8022cffcfb26</RequestId></ItemLookupErrorResponse>
```

Please Help me, to solve this error. I also used the below code but it giving me the same error:-

```
    http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AKIAI45CVYPQ53IQWI3A
]&
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=0316067938&
ResponseGroup=Reviews&
TruncateReviewsAt="256"&
IncludeReviewsSummary="False"&
Version=2013-08-01
&Timestamp=[2015-07-16T15:32:47Z]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following article explains how to generate the signature:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html

timstamp value should be encoded like this Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z

Comment: I told u to generate url using the above doc. i think u only change timestamp in url only. U could also change in signature.